# How to put two subfloats side-by-side, which use 100 % of the text width?

Tags: subfloats

In `draft`-mode a black marker indicates that the reserved space is too low. This also appears in the following example, but it shouldn't. How can I put two `subfloat`s exactly side-by-side?

```
\documentclass[draft=on]{scrbook}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \subfloat{
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
      TEXT1
    \end{minipage}
  }%
  \subfloat{
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
      TEXT2
    \end{minipage}
  }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please compare (spaces removed):

```
\documentclass[draft=on]{scrbook}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \subfloat{%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
      TEXT1
    \end{minipage}%
}%
  \subfloat{%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
      TEXT2
    \end{minipage}%
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```